# Moving a googlecode project from svn to mercurial. Any tricks?

Tags: svn, mercurial, google-code

I am maintaining a project on googlecode. I am using svn and I am happy with that.

However, a new contributor would like to use Mercurial. I am ok with this this because I think that it is a better choice when working with different people.

So I am to the point to migrate my googlecode project from svn to hg. I would like to know if some of you already dit that and if there are some tricks in the migration process?

For example, Does it keep the history of changes? Anything else I should know?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you have a look at the google code FAQ already? There is a [document](http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/ConvertingSvnToHg) describing two ways of changing from Subversion to Mercurial where one includes the transfer of the complete commit history to Mercurial.

See: http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/ConvertingSvnToHg

Comment: Thanks for this link. Some alternatives are given in the comments. Have you tried them? WHat would you recommend?